# inserting data from azure blob and depending on the name of the blob insert into certain table in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

So basically my issue is this, I will use metadata to get the names of the files from a source folder in the storage account in azure. I need to parse that name and insert it into a respective table. example below.

File name would be in this format.    customer_GUIID_TypeOfData_other information.csv
i.e. 1c56d6s4s33s4_Sales_09112021.csv
156468a5s5s54_Inventory_08022021.csv

so these are 2 different customers and two different types of information.

the tables in SQL will be exactly that without the date. 156468a5s5s54_Inventory  or 1c56d6s4s33s4_Sales
how can I copy the data from the CSV to the respective table depending on the file name? I will also need to insert or update existing rows in the destination table based on a unique identifier in the file dataset using AZURE Data Factory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the file name using `Get Metadata` activity and copy data from CSV to Azure SQL table using `Dataflow` activity with Upsert enable.

**Input blob files:**

[image]

**Step1**:

•   Create a **Delimiter** Source dataset. Create a parameter for a filename to pass it dynamically.

•   Create **Azure SQL database** Sink dataset and create a parameter to pass table name dynamically.

*Source dataset*:

[image]

*Sink dataset*:

[image]

**Step2**:

•   Connect Source dataset to Get Metadata activity and pass “*.csv” as the file name to get a list of all file names from blob folder.

[image]

*Output of Get Metada*:

[image]

**Step3**:

•   Connect the output of `Get Metadata` activity to ForEach loop, to load all the incoming Source files/data to Sink.

•   Add expression to the items to get the child items from previous activity.

```
@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childitems
```

[image]

**Step4**:

•   Add `dataflow` activity inside foreach loop.

•   Connect Source to Source dataset.

*Dataflow Source*:

[image]

**Step5**:

•   Connect Sink to Sink dataset.

[image]

•   Enable **Allow upsert** to update if record exists based on unique key column.

[image]

**Step6**:

•   Add `AlterRow` between source and sink to add condition for upsert.

•   **Upsert** when unique key column is not null or is found.

> Upsert if:  isNull(id)==false()

[image]

**Step7**:

•   In the `ForEach` loop, **dataflow** settings, add expressions for source filename and sink table name dynamically.

> Src_file_name:  @item().name

•   As we are extracting the sink table name from the source file name. Split the file name based on underscore “**_**” and then combine 1st 2 strings to eliminate the date part.

> Sink_tbname: `@concat(split(item().name, '_')[0],'_',split(item().name, '_')[1])`

[image]

**Step8**:

When the pipeline is run, you can see the loop executes the number of source files in the blob and loads data to respective tables based on the file name.

[image]

Comment: how would I be able to handle multiple file types, for instance, if they upload an excel file or a text file?  the client was wanting to be able to upload CSV, TXT, and XLS. file types.

Comment: I was thinking on step 2 instead of passing *.csv can I pass the whole file name and then in the dataflow have multiple sources for each file type?

Comment: I followed the example and it is saying UniqueID is not found which is a unique identifier column in the CSV file. your example has id

Comment: You can process all types of files by mentioning "*" instead of "*.csv". If you provide a full file name in step2, you can process only a single file to the target.  In order to perform an upsert operation, there should be a unique  (common) column key between source and destination.

Comment: Please go through this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-alter-row) for more understanding.